# PHP APC keeps clearing itself

Tags: php, caching, apc, shared-hosting

I'm using the APC (Alternative PHP Cache) and after I store some entries the whole cache just clears after a bit, usually a few minutes. When I store the entries I'm not defining a ttl and the ttl in the config is 0, so I'm not sure why all the entries keep getting deleted. The uptime seems to always be 0 minutes so perhaps it's restarting for some reason?

APC Settings (GoDaddy Shared Hosting Linux Server)

```
apc.cache_by_default    1
apc.canonicalize    1
apc.coredump_unmap  0
apc.enable_cli  0
apc.enabled 1
apc.file_md5    0
apc.file_update_protection  2
apc.filters 
apc.gc_ttl  3600
apc.include_once_override   0
apc.lazy_classes    0
apc.lazy_functions  0
apc.max_file_size   1M
apc.mmap_file_mask  
apc.num_files_hint  1000
apc.preload_path    
apc.report_autofilter   0
apc.rfc1867 0
apc.rfc1867_freq    0
apc.rfc1867_name    APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix  upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl 3600
apc.serializer  default
apc.shm_segments    1
apc.shm_size    32M
apc.shm_strings_buffer  4M
apc.slam_defense    1
apc.stat    1
apc.stat_ctime  0
apc.ttl 0
apc.use_request_time    1
apc.user_entries_hint   4096
apc.user_ttl    0
apc.write_lock  1
```

Comment: Same problem here. Dedicated server.